# How to view all pulls from bare repository?

Tags: git, git-pull

I am holding the bare repository of a git project. Is it possible to see, if someone pulls from it or get a list of all pulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by default Git does not log or provide audit log.

An [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#auth) like **[Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html)** does provide such an audit.
It is in front of Git (and intercept ssh queries), and records events in  `~/.gitolite/logs`.